# C CryptUnprotectData crashes Program

Tags: c

Hi im trying to write a C Program that decrypts the Key that Chrome uses to encrypt saved Passwords. The Key is encrypted with CryptProtectData and then encoded with Base64, i have sucessfully decoded the Key and now i want to decrypt it with CryptUnprotectData but when i try to use this function my Program just crashes, i had a similar Problem once when I got the size of the byte* holding the encrypted data wrong. Does anyone know what i did wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <base64.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>

void main()
{    
  //RFBBUEk = DPAPI    
  char B64[] = "BAAAA0Iyd3wEV0RGMegDAT8KX6wEAAAAYUduGi5FwQr1+XlafMqBZAAAAAAIAAAAAABBmAAAAAQAAIAAAALIvW98pXJMaQ0aJPpr40c12oSSRDg59tr+zaF+podlvAAAAAA6AAAAAAgAAIAAAAD2z5W4nMDHLOxthH8nXyxl+1hpRdY2BGHStxaDvgjSiMAAAAIKrcLbXw5WZCPjqyPtO/3QahMa0yMRC/CoMS/OoDw5j7fcZ8N31sIildXpN82egDEAAAAAvzHS7+Zf2IR05cggu1XHfNGknq3TKRHW37CVEktIHHu6yo1K0Q0r5YevYDUUNdhzlpJ+ynQUTBAS2Fa3PRR4V";
  int len = sizeof(B64);
  int * flen;
  char * ergebnis;
  ergebnis = unbase64(B64,len,flen);
  DATA_BLOB Input,Output;
  Input.pbData = (byte*)ergebnis;
  Input.cbData = *flen;
  CryptUnprotectData(&Input,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,&Output);
  printf("%s",(char*)Output.pbData);
  getchar();  
}
```

Comment: Are you decrypting from the same machine you used to encrypt?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/23201146

Comment: Are you sure that CryptUnprotectData is the line your program is crashing on?

Comment: yes, i use the same machine on which the data was encrypted, when i comment out the line with CryptUnprotectData the program doesnt crash and waits for me to press enter because of getchar();

Comment: Does `unbase64` somehow allocate memory for `flen` because it never has its value set? (Rhetorical, it can’t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  printf("%s",(char*)Output.pbData);
```

First, you don't check if `CryptUnprotectData` succeeds. If it fails, you're passing a pointer to garbage to `printf`.

Second, how are you expecting `printf` to know how many bytes to print? You need to do something with `Output.cbData`.

Lastly, `flen` is never assigned a value. You pass whatever nonsense, uninitialized value it has to `unbase64` and then try to use that value.

Comment: Are you saying that is not a null-terminated C string?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is not a null-terminated C string. That's why he has to cast the pointer to `char*`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work by giving flen a value and making an if statement that prints OK when CryptUnprotectData is sucessful